# How to publish azure function in python using docker from my machine to azure?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-functions-core-tools

when I'm trying to publish my azure function in python to azure I get this following error.

```
pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
ERROR: cannot install cryptography-2.7 dependency: binary dependencies without wheels are not supported.  Use the --build-native-deps option to automatically build and configure the dependencies using a Docker container. More information at https://aka.ms/func-python-publish
```

So, I have install docker and I have tried to push my function using the following command

func azure functionapp publish timertriggerforstreaming --build-native-deps

I didn't do anything I have just installed docker, 
when I tried to publish I get the following error when I was using docker on windows container(My machine is windows 10).

```
Error running docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:2.0.12493-python3.6-buildenv.
output: 2.0.12493-python3.6-buildenv: Pulling from azure-functions/python
image operating system "Linux" cannot be used on this platform
```

Again I switch from Windows to Linux and again tried the same now it's taking a long time and I'm seeing the following output for a long time.
[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyD6X.png)
Is the way I'm doing it right or wrong, or I need to Dockerize azure function on my own and to publish it

Comment: what do you mean by this? "Again I switch from Windows to Linux and again tried the same now it's taking a long time." You need to switch to Linux containers in Docker  for Windows to make this work.

Comment: please the updated post @silent

Comment: Well this just means that the initial docker pull is still running. Depending on large the image is and your internet connection this might take a while the first time. Should be much quicker afterwards

Comment: oh, okay Is python is only available on Linux environment in azure?

Comment: yes. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker#overview

Answer (score 0):

Follow this doc for deployment : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image